# three.js import ERROR 404 ( File Not Found ) for a existing file

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

**GET http://localhost:port/js/three net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)**

I am trying to make a web-dev project of my own using Three JS.
I have downloaded ThreeJS master Zip from [Three JS Official Website](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/archive/master.zip)

Copied the JS files from Build folder and have started to work on the project.

My Dir Structure Looks Like:

[image]

And imported ThreeJS in my JS File ( Globe.js ) as :

```
import * as THREE from './three'
```

Script in My index.html inside  as i want the element in a div inside body.

`<script type="module" src="./js/globe.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2):

**Figured it Out**

---

Read Readme for Three JS and found i imported it wrong in  my JS file

It should be as :

```
import * as THREE from './three.js'
```

what a silly mistake !! LMAO